# QPixmap and GUI threading

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm trying to get a small example up and running with a Thread doing a screenshot and sending it to the GUI application to be shown. But I am getting this "error"

```
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
```

I've tried read around the, but are having difficulties understanding why exactly it's giving me this since the QImage is made within the main application and also the GUI thread?

I'd like my label to show the image captured by the thread.

```
class Main(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 280, 600)
        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.testButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Click Me")
        self.connect(self.testButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.Capture)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.testButton)

        self.label_ = QLabel(self)
        self.label_.move(280, 120)
        self.label_.resize(640, 480)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label_)


    @pyqtSlot(QImage) 
    def ChangeFrame(self, image):  
        qimg = QImage(image.data, image.shape[1], image.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)

        self.label_.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(qimg))


    def Capture(self):       
        self.thread_ = CaptureScreen()        
        self.connect(self.thread_, QtCore.SIGNAL("ChangeFrame(PyQt_PyObject)"), self.ChangeFrame, Qt.DirectConnection)
        self.thread_.start()       

class CaptureScreen(QtCore.QThread):
    pixmap = pyqtSignal(QImage)

    def __del__(self):
        self.exiting = True
        self.wait()

    def run(self):    
        img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(100,10,400,780))
        img_np = np.array(img)
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)        

        self.emit( QtCore.SIGNAL("ChangeFrame(PyQt_PyObject)"), frame)



app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
test = Main()
test.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html):

> [Direct Connection](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) The slot is invoked immediately, when the signal is emitted. The slot is executed in the emitter's thread, which is not necessarily the receiver's thread.

By specifying `Qt.DirectConnection` when connecting your signal you're causing the connected method to be called by your `CaptureScreen` thread, meaning that you're creating a QPixmap outside of your GUI thread.

Does changing the connection type to `Qt.QueuedConnection` fix things?

Comment: yes it did fix it. But now it closes if I click the button again.

Comment: I guess that's another problem to be solved :) Thanks alot for the help. Much appreciated!